# Keep hidden directories hidden when syncing with rsync (on macOS)

Tags: rsync, macos

I am on macOS, and am making a backup of one of my external drives to another external drive using the following terminal command:

```
rsync -ahbAX --info=progress2 --stats --delete --backup-dir=/Volumes/BackupDrive/BackupDir/ /Volumes/MyDrive /Volumes/BackupDrive
```

To my knowledge, the `-A` and `-X` flags should preserve pretty much all extended attributes. And for the most part, it seems to—Finder "tags" are preserved, even though those are the extended attributes I've seen a lot of programs outright ignore (e.g. when uploading to Google Drive).

However, there are some folders on my source drive which I hid using `chflags hidden folder`. These aren't also hidden in the Backup Drive.

How do I copy this 'hidden nature' over? I tried using the `-E` flag but got the same error.